# How to use jenv with Fish shell on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, fish

I downloaded `jenv` using the official instructions, added it to the PATH and then tried to init it, using the command given in the instructions, but it throws the following error:

```
> source (jenv init -|psub)

Command 'hash' not found, did you mean:
  command 'bash' from deb bash (5.1-2ubuntu1)
  command 'sash' from deb sash (3.8-5)
  ...
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
/tmp/.psub.LxsYuMSHNC (line 1): 
hash -r
^
from sourcing file /tmp/.psub.LxsYuMSHNC
    called on line 14 of file /tmp/.psub.Z8yofQashD
in function 'jenv' with arguments 'rehash'
    called on line 7 of file /tmp/.psub.lD4Y0jQZfO
from sourcing file /tmp/.psub.lD4Y0jQZfO
```

I understand that the `hash` utility is a bash utility, but can you somehow make it work in fish? There is official documentation for it, there exist fisher plugins for it, so I doubt that it is not supported at all.

I have found [one post that describes my problem on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fishshell/comments/hs4dh3/anyone_using_jenv_under_fish_shell_im_getting_a/), but it is rather old, and the solution does not work for me.

I temporarily fixed it by using `source (jenv init --no-rehash -|psub)` instead of the official command, which skips the hash function altogether. Is there any way to make it work without the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the best workaround at the moment.

[This note](https://github.com/jenv/jenv#3-known-issues) at the bottom of the README mentions its known Fish issues, and [this issue](https://github.com/jenv/jenv/issues/333) mentions that the maintainer doesn't have time for the project any longer, and recommends [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com) and [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io) as "better" options than jenv.

I've used asdf under Fish, but it's been over a year.  I don't recall how well it ran, nor did I use it to manage Java versions.  I seem to recall minor installation issues, but I believe these were due to my personal environment preference.

But it may be worth giving asdf or SDKMan a try based on the current maintenance status of `jenv` and its known issues with Fish.

Comment: Thanks for the links, that really did help me out. What's weird is, that on my macbook with fish shell installed, jenv works perfectly fine. Just ubuntu makes problems.

Comment: @MauriceNino I agree, that *is* odd.  Perhaps a version difference (likely jenv, but possibly Fish)?

Comment: Same version, just checked. With these kinds of inconsistencies, it is probably best to stay away from `jenv`. I will probably use `asdf`, as it looks a bit better (subjectively).

Comment: Just as a little update. I have successfully installed `jenv` on ubuntu 21 today. The fisher plugin still throws the same error, but adding `.jenv/bin` to the `fish_user_path` and then executing `source (jenv init -|psub)` worked for me.

Comment: @MauriceNino That's good to hear.  You might consider adding that as an answer for others to find.  Probably even self-accept it.  I'll mourn the loss of 15 rep briefly, then move on :-)

Comment: As the fisher plugin still throws the exact same error, I would say it is pretty unstable on fish shell and I would still recommend looking for alternatives. My comment is merely a little hint for people who really want to get it to work :)